# Redirection rule in apache with subDomain?

Tags: apache-2.2

greetings all, i have multi sub-domain on my domainname.com , i need to redirect www.*.domainname.com to *.domainname.com

ex: http://www.sub1.domainname.com to http ://sub1.domainname.com

any ideas how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Before using it, make sure you have enabled mod_rewrite first.